# Can I run php script under user permissions with FastCGI and APACHE?

Tags: php, apache, cgi, fastcgi

I would like to install Apache and PHP but I have read that mod_php is very slow. Many php developers have adviced me to use FastCGI.

Can I run my php script with a specific user:group? (each vhost has different user:group)

I know there is suphp but is slow too..

Thank you so much!