# Change user PHP

Tags: php, unix, posix, centos

I need to change the user of a PHP script at runtime. I've looked at `posix_setuid`, but it looks unsecure and requires root privaledges. What would be preferable is changing the user id of the script with the users password (something like `posix_setuid($username, $password)`), and avoiding running the script as root.

I'm open to other methods, and the script doesn't necessarily need to be PHP. However, it is going to be called from apache.

A good anology to the scenario would be how cPanel su's to the currently logged in user on it's file manager.

I need to change the user because I'm creating a file manager for a multi-user setup. Currently, I have the file manager set up so that apache serves my PHP file manager as root. However, this is not reasonable, because in case of a security bug in the code, one user can edit files on the entire server.

I'm looking for a way to SU the script to the logged in user so that in case of a security flaw, the user is only restricted to their own files.

Comment: Why do you need to change user at runtime? Maybe the problem can be solved in another way?

Comment: I'm open to another way to solve the problem. If you think you have an alternative, then feel free to go ahead and post it.

Comment: Suggesting an alternative would depend on what you felt you needed to change the user for, but you've not explained this in your question

Comment: Ok, hopefully I've made it clear enough what I am using this for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I needed to do this a while ago. I basically created a bash script which accessed resources that only root had access to. Here's what I did:

Use the `visudo` command to change your `/etc/sudoers`:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
apache ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/myscript.sh
```

I have added the line which allows the `apache` user to run `/sbin/myscript.sh` with the sudo command without entering the password.

After that, you can just put the following in your php file to get the output:

```
$output = shell_exec("sudo /sbin/myscript.sh");
```

Comment: This sounds like a possible solution. I'll investigate this further, and mark it as the right answer if it yields desirable results.

Answer (score 1):

[This recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915333/can-i-run-php-script-under-user-permissions-with-fastcgi-and-apache/5915447#5915447) discusses two options for doing this with PHP:

- PHP + FastCGI with suexec
- suPHP

Comment: Problem with this answer is that I need to change users depending on the user who is logged in. If I do it this way, I'm hardcoded to one user only.

Comment: **Running** as a user refers to the permissions of an entire process on the system.  In order to implement some business functionality in a PHP application with different permissions for each authenticated user, you don't need to change the running process' permissions.  If you could make your requirements (original question) more clear as to what you're trying to accomplish (e.g. "In my application, I only want users to be able to manage widgets that belong to them") we can probably help you better.